# parsing Plist file in android

Tags: android

In my project parsing plist file using android.
I have downloaded so many example from the internet and also shown the stack overflow answer.

but i can not parse my plist file .

please tell me how to start plist parsing in droid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a parser lib named [android-plist-parser](https://github.com/tenaciousRas/android-plist-parser).

Sample code (from the project tests):

```
PListXMLHandler handler = new PListXMLHandler();
parser.setHandler(handler);
parser.parse(/* plist content as String */);
PList actualPList = ((PListXMLHandler) parser.getHandler()).getPlist();
// use actualPList
```

Comment: thank you ..i am see this example and run it but how can use this example in my project.

Comment: add the jar to your `lib` folder and use the library?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [xmlwise](https://code.google.com/p/xmlwise/), its rather simple to use.

```
Map<String, Object> properties = Plist.fromXml(xmlString);
```