# Parsing XML-Plist from string

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to parse a plist on android but I've tried to import several libraries but they all failed to compile.

Here's the plist to decode.
http://www.ctbsolutions.com.my/rapidpg/eta.aspx?bid=B0377

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>busstop</key>
            <string>Sek Men Chung Ling (P)</string>
            <key>busstopID</key>
            <string>2/A/JAYI12</string>
            <key>busstopLat</key>
            <string>5.40515</string>
            <key>busstopLong</key>
            <string>100.29390</string>
            <key>details</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>arrivingTime</key>
                    <string>5 mins</string>
                    <key>routeLat</key>
                    <string>5.41690</string>
                    <key>routeLong</key>
                    <string>100.30914</string>
                    <key>routeNumber</key>
                    <string>306</string>
                    <key>toLocation</key>
                    <string>Hospital P.Pinang</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>arrivingTime</key>
                    <string>7 mins</string>
                    <key>routeLat</key>
                    <string>5.41386</string>
                    <key>routeLong</key>
                    <string>100.32806</string>
                    <key>routeNumber</key>
                    <string>203</string>
                    <key>toLocation</key>
                    <string>Pejabat Pos Ayer Itam</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>arrivingTime</key>
                    <string>7 mins</string>
                    <key>routeLat</key>
                    <string>5.41377</string>
                    <key>routeLong</key>
                    <string>100.32803</string>
                    <key>routeNumber</key>
                    <string>502</string>
                    <key>toLocation</key>
                    <string>Hub Pekan Genting</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>arrivingTime</key>
                    <string>At Terminal Jetty 1</string>
                    <key>routeLat</key>
                    <string>5.41422</string>
                    <key>routeLong</key>
                    <string>100.34219</string>
                    <key>routeNumber</key>
                    <string>203</string>
                    <key>toLocation</key>
                    <string>Terminal Jetty 1</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>arrivingTime</key>
                    <string>At Terminal Jetty 1</string>
                    <key>routeLat</key>
                    <string>5.41491</string>
                    <key>routeLong</key>
                    <string>100.34256</string>
                    <key>routeNumber</key>
                    <string>502</string>
                    <key>toLocation</key>
                    <string>Terminal Jetty 1</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</plist>
```

I've done the part where it gets the data online and saves it in a String. But there are no examples of how I can decode this or at least all examples are too old to be used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parsing Plist file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972706/parsing-plist-file-in-android)

Comment: what do you mean fail to compile? Can you show some code that you have problems with? Maybe you are importing or using them wrong.